# How can I delete the Form Templates Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, template, hub-site

I recently created a Hub Site on SharePoint Online and associated 3 sites to the Hub Site. All fine so far. 
However, in the Site Contents of each site is a Document Library called 'Form Templates'.

This is causing confusion because there is a folder in another Document Library that the users should be using called 'Forms Templates' (similar but different)

So my question is how can I delete the Form Template document library ? There is no option to do so but there is on the Document Libraries I create.

[image]

Or do I have to keep it as it's an essential part of the Hub site set up ?

All help appreciated.

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to delete the default library which was created by Sharepoint itself - it will have some side effect to the setup.

One of the most advice is to not touch default SharePoint libraries such as:

- Documents
- Form Templates
- Style Library

Reference document:

[Hide SharePoint library or list](https://blog.lsonline.fr/2019/02/09/hide-sharepoint-library-or-list/)

**What should we do in this scenario?**

For your scenario, you can create the folder with the name something like 'Forms Templates Folder' or appending just with 2

With these being said, still, we can hide these libraries (deletion is not recommended) using the following ways:

**Using PnP Provisioning template:**

```
Set-PnPList -Identity "Demo List" -Hidden $true
```

Or

```
<pnp:ListInstance Title="Style Library" Description="Use the style library to store style sheets, such as CSS or XSL files. The style sheets in this gallery can be used by this site or any of its subsites." DocumentTemplate="" TemplateType="101" Url="Style Library" TemplateFeatureID="00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101" Hidden="true">
    <pnp:ContentTypeBindings>
        <pnp:ContentTypeBinding ContentTypeID="0x0101" Default="true" />
        <pnp:ContentTypeBinding ContentTypeID="0x0120" />
    </pnp:ContentTypeBindings>
</pnp:ListInstance>
```

**Using SharePoint Designer**

Example below:
[image]

Comment: Hiding it might be option. But messing about with SharePoint Designer is a definite no go where I am. Thanks for the suggestions - much appreciated. Dan

Comment: Definitely we can hide the list using the PnP but deletion is not at all recommended... if the above answer helps you, could you please mark as answer, it will help to upcoming visitors for the same issue.. thanks for the understanding :-)

Comment: Done :-) Thanks again